# Verify digital signature using BIGNUM library

Tags: c, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature, bignum

why is my code returning weird result?

```
void printBN(char *msg, BIGNUM * a)
{
    char * number_str = BN_bn2hex(a);
    printf("%s %s\n", msg, number_str);
    OPENSSL_free(number_str);
}

int main () 
{
    BN_CTX *ctx = BN_CTX_new();

    BIGNUM *e = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *n = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *d = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *plaintxt = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *signature = BN_new();

    BN_hex2bn(&signature, "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");
    BN_hex2bn(&n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
    BN_hex2bn(&e, "10001");

    BN_mod_exp(plaintxt, signature, e, n, ctx);
    printBN("hash value: \n", plaintxt);

}
```

My code gives the following result, which doesn't look like correct result of the calculation:

```
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
```

Comment: Please do not forget to accept answers (including your own ones) if your question has been answered. It's that big V next to the answer on the left. You can change that decision later by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the correct result to me, except that you are missing the initial byte, because it is [defined](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2) (PKCS#1 v2.2) to be `00`:

Header byte:

```
01
```

PKCS#1 v1.5 padding characters:

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

end of padding character:

```
00
```

ASN.1 encoding of hash OID and hash value:

```
3031300D060960864801650304020105000420BC5F9353CBB9DCAE86B9F8F68C1C95856DB836ACA2E00C9319716CDF4DD0F5
```

which [decodes](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEILxfk1PLudyuhrn49owclYVtuDasouAMkxlxbN9N0PW6) (Lapo's ASN.1 decoder) to:

```
SEQUENCE (2 elem)
  SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 sha-256 (NIST Algorithm)
    NULL
  OCTET STRING (32 byte) BC5F9353CBB9DCAE86B9F8F68C1C95856DB836ACA2E00C9319716CDF4DD0F5BA
```

Where the contents of the octet string (byte array in hex) is the hash value.

---

I guess it is just a bit more complex than you initially thought. Try PSS, it is even more complex (but also more secure). Note that there are [many attacks on "raw" or "textbook" RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20085/1172) (just modular exponentiation). Such padding is required to have a secure signature or - in case of encryption - ciphertext.

Comment: Is there a C library function that can decode ASN.1 string?

Comment: Generally only included in crypto libraries, even though ASN.1 originated at the telco (X.500 standards) if I'm not mistaken. Of course OpenSSL has it, Crypto++ no doubt as well if you want C++. Certificates are defined in ASN.1 and DER encoded, and they actually contain X.500 encoded information. There are specialized libs and even specialized *companies* around. But note that the ASN.1 string in PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is basically constant given a hash function (so you can take the header and then simply paste the hash value into the octet string).

Comment: `openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in <yourfile.der>` :)

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica the question need 'c' tag that I can't add

Comment: The missing result is due to the `BN_mod_exp`?

Comment: Sorry, which missing result is that? The question only performs modular exponentiation, it needs some additional code to achieve verification result (boolean true / false and possibly error in case of incorrectly sized input).

Comment: @Deus - *"Is there a C library function that can decode ASN.1 string?"* - GNU has [libtasn1](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtasn1/). It is used by several GNU packages, including GnuTLS, GnuPG and P11Kit.

Comment: So i see that "3031300D060960864801650304020105000420BC5F9353CBB9DCAE86B9F8F68C1C95856DB836ACA2E00C9319716CDF4DD0F5BA" is the ASN1 encoded hash value, so what's the proper way to remove the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding characters?

Comment: Is the end of padding character always 00?

Comment: Did you read the RFC that I linked to? At this point I think you should have followed the links provided. Generally you don't remove them at all: please see steps 3 and 4 of the [verification operation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#section-8.2.2). The start of the padding (leftmost, most significant byte) is always `00` because it is defined like that. Usually it is either `00` or `01` to allow for key sizes that are not a multiple of 8 bits. Similarly, the end of padding byte has an explicit value in the standard.